# SharePoint Online Conditional JSON formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

New to this, real Noob.

I have a SP list column named rating, based on the value I need to change the cell color.

- Value 1 to 3 -  Green.
- Value 4 to 6 - Yellow.
- Value 8 to 12 - Orange.
- Value 15 to 25 - Red.

Would someone please be able to help with the code/syntax.
Really appreciate the assistance, out of my depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try JSON below and modify as needed. In your condition, you have not mentioned the color for the value outside the condition, that is, else condition. I used "gray", but you can change it to your liking.

You can visit [MS site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) for more JSON formatting examples.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >=1 && @currentField <=3, 'Green', if(@currentField >=4 && @currentField <=6, 'Yellow', if(@currentField >=8 && @currentField <=12, 'Orange', if(@currentField >=15 && @currentField <=25, 'Red', 'gray'))))",
    "color": "black",
    "font-size": "2.0em",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Matiur, Thank you!!!!! That is perfect, exactly what I was after.
Really appreciate the help.